# Are spatial queries possible using Python and cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, cx-oracle, nearest-neighbor, sdo

I am trying to execute a spatial query on an Oracle spatial table via python using the cx_Oracle package.

I can make generic queries successfully, but when I try a spatial query it results in errors.

This is what I have tried:

```
import cx_Oracle
...

lon = -120.494352
lat = 36.585289

# open a connection to oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('myuser/mypass@spatialdb')

# create a cursor
cur = con.cursor()

# Create and populate Oracle objects
typeObj = con.gettype("MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")
elementInfoTypeObj = con.gettype("MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY")
ordinateTypeObj = con.gettype("MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY")
obj = typeObj.newobject()
obj.SDO_GTYPE = 2001
obj.SDO_SRID = 8307
obj.SDO_ELEM_INFO = elementInfoTypeObj.newobject()
obj.SDO_ELEM_INFO.extend([1, 1, 1])
obj.SDO_ORDINATES = ordinateTypeObj.newobject()
obj.SDO_ORDINATES.extend([lon, lat])
print("Created object", obj)

# set up a distance-calculating sql statement
sql = "select id into :id from spatialtbl s where sdo_nn(s.geometry, :obj, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1) = 'TRUE'"

try:
    # execute the distance sql
    cur.execute(sql, id=id, obj=obj)
    print(f'The id is {id.getvalue()}')
except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
    print(error)
```

which results in the error:

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong code-wise or if spatial queries are even possible using Python and cx_Oracle? The cx_Oracle documentation doesn't specifically address this as far as I can tell/find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a brief mention in the documentation:

- [Binding Spatial Datatypes](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-spatial-datatypes)

Here are two examples from the cx_Oracle source code repository:

- [InsertGeometry.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/InsertGeometry.py)
- [SpatialToGeoPandas.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/SpatialToGeoPandas.py)

Here's a presentation from the recent Oracle Conference:

- [Analyzing Location-based Patterns with Python and Oracle Database](https://events.rainfocus.com/widget/oracle/oow19/catalogcodeone19?search=DEV6706)
  The download links are there but may not be obvious [pdf](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow19/sess/1567055692336001tHDH/PF/Lapp-DEV6706_1569248669990001icNf.pdf) and [zip](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow19/sess/1567055692336001tHDH/PF/notebooks_1569248880491001ehDe.zip).

In your example, you probably need to do at least `id = cursor.var(int)`, see [Bind Direction](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#bind-direction) so cx_Oracle knows what to do with the value you are getting from the DB.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I was able to find an answer after your links made me think about it again. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

I think the "select into" was the problem (reserved for pl/sql?).

By doing the following I was able to obtain the answer:

```
# set up a distance-calculating sql statement
sql = """select id from spatialtbl s where sdo_nn(s.geometry, :ob, 'sdo_num_res=1', 1) = 'TRUE'"""

try:
    # execute the distance sql
    cur.execute(sql, ob=obj)
    id = cur.fetchone()
    print(f'The id is {id}')
except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
    print(error)
```

Comment: That would help!